# Web Crawler is printing the first text it sees when executed

Tags: php, web-crawler

I have been trying to code a web crawler using this patched code given below, unfortunately, it is echoing the starting text it sees in the site rather than the text I particularly asked it to fetch

Have no idea where I did wrong

**CODE GOES AS:**

```
        function get_datab($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
    $returned_content = get_datab('https://soovle.com/top/');
        $first_step = explode( '<div class="column"' , $returned_content );
        $second_step = explode('</div>', $first_step[0]);
        $third_step = explode('<div class="letter"', $second_step[1]);
        $fourth_step = explode('<div class="correction"', $third_step[0]);

    foreach ($fourth_step as $key=>$element) {

    $head = 'https://soovle.com/top/';
    $child_first = explode( '<span' , $element );
    $child_second = explode( '</span>' , $child_first[0] );
    $link = $head . trim($child_second[0], '\'"');
    $final = "<a target = '_blank' style='font-style: normal;' href=\"".$link."</a></br>";


    echo $final;

    if($key==10){
            break;
        }
    }
```

The URL that I m trying to parse is "https://soovle.com/top/"

Any Help is Appreciated..

Comment: `foreach ($fourth_step as $key=>$element) {
    if ($i < 3) {
       $i++;
    continue;
}` What is the purpose of this? Are you missing a `}` or not?

Comment: I can't see the word *'nothing'* anywhere in your code, is that coming from the site your scrapping? Why are you not using a HTML parser like [domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: @dustytrash edited the question, please check and revert